# Not sure how to specify the app for Celery

Tags: django, docker, django-celery

Below is the structure for my app:

```
- anp_tasks
  - __init__.py
  - celery.py
  - tasks.py
- platform
  - webapp
    - app
      [entire django project]
    - manage.py
  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- docker-compose.yml
```

Dockerfile contents

```
FROM python:latest
LABEL maintainer="Akrogoniaios Technologies Corp."

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc libjpeg-dev libc-dev musl-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev apt-utils

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

#copy the app files and proceed

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./webapp /app

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static
```

requirements.txt

```
Django>=3.1
djangorestframework>=3.12
psycopg2==2.8.3
celery>=5.0.2
```

**init**.py inside **anp_tasks**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

__all__ = ['anp_tasks']
```

contents of **celery.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('anp_tasks',
         broker='amqp://',
         backend='rpc://',
         include=['anp_tasks.tasks'])

app.conf.update(
    result_expires=3600,
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

Contents of tasks.py inside **anp_tasks*

```
from .celery import app

@app.task
def print_hello():
    print ("hello there")
```

Contents of docker-compose.yml specific to celery

```
broker:
    image: rabbitmq:latest
env_file:
    - ./platform/anp_rabbitmq.env
volumes:
    - "./rabbitmq:/data"

worker:
    build:
        context: ./platform
command: "celery -A .\anp_tasks worker -l INFO "
environment:
    - DEBUG=1
depends_on:
    - broker
```

However, when I run docker-compose up, it throws the below error.

```
worker_1    | Usage: celery [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
worker_1    | 
worker_1    | Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
worker_1    | Unable to load celery application.
worker_1    | While trying to load the module .np_tasks the following error occurred:
worker_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
worker_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 50, in convert
worker_1    |     return find_app(value)
worker_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 384, in find_app
worker_1    |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
worker_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
worker_1    |     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
worker_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 107, in import_from_cwd
worker_1    |     return imp(module, package=package)
worker_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
worker_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
worker_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
worker_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
worker_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
worker_1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '\x07np_tasks'
worker_1    | 
anp_mvp_worker_1 exited with code 2
```

How do I specify the app path to the celery?

Comment: With a backslash `\a` is a control character.  Do you mean a Linux-style front slash, `./anp_tasks`, or perhaps a Python module name `anp_tasks` without a path separator at all?

Comment: @DavidMaze: Fixed that error, it is suppose to be ./anp_tasks. I have tried without the path separator as well. It did not make any difference.